# How to achieve code splitting + SSR with @loadable/component ? Is webpack needed for the server code?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering, loadable-component

I'm trying to add code splitting + SSR to my React web app using `@loadable/component`.

**My current situation:** This is how I've implemented SSR for robots on my website. Since it's just for robots, I'm not using `hydrate`. Basically, I send either the `index.html` with the JS bundle's script tags for a regular user, or I send a fully rendered HTML page for the robots, without the need to `hydrate`.

**My goal:** I'd like to use `@loadable/component` to always return SSR pages from my server, and use `hydrate` to attach my JS bundle. And also achieve code splitting with that.

Here is how I currently build my app (pseudo code):

```
1. webpack BUILD FOR entry { app: "src/index.tsx" } AND OUTPUT BUNDLES TO MY /public FOLDER
2. babel TRANSPILE WHOLE `/src` FOLDER AND OUTPUT FILES TO MY /dist_app FOLDER
```

It's basically 2 builds, one of them is using webpack to bundle, and the other one basically transpiles the files from `src` to `distApp`.

And this is what my server does (pseudo code)

```
1. CHECK IF USER IS ROBOT (FROM THE USER AGENT STRING)
2. IF REGULAR USER
     res.send("public/index.html");   // SEND REGULAR index.html WITH JS BUNDLES GENERATED BY WEBPACK
   IF ROBOT
     const App = require("./dist_app/App");          // THIS IS THE src/App COMPONENT TRANSPILED BY BABEL
     const ssrHtml = ReactDOM.renderToString(<App/>);
     // ADD <head> <helmet> <styles> ETC
     res.send(ssrHtml);
```

The steps described above works just fine for my initial requirements (ssr just for robots).

But after I added `@loadable/component` to achieve code splitting + SSR, the set up above does not work anymore.

Because now I have `dynamic imports` on some of my routes. For example:

```
const AsyncPage = loadable(() => import("@app/pages/PageContainer"));
```

So my `renderToString(<App/>)` call comes back mostly empty, because it does not load those `AsyncPages`.

Over on the docs for [Loadable components: server side rendering](https://loadable-components.com/docs/server-side-rendering/) they have an [example repo](https://github.com/gregberge/loadable-components/tree/master/examples/server-side-rendering) on how to achieve this.

But their example is kind of complex and it seems they are using `webpack` inside the server. I'll post what they do on their server below.

**QUESTION**

Do I really have to use `webpack` to bundle my app's server code in order to use `@loadable/component` for SSR like they are showing in their example? Can't I just use some kind of `babel` plugin to convert the `dynamic imports` into regular `require` calls? So that I'll be able to render it the way I was doing before?

It's weird, that they use `webpack-dev-middleware`. It's like this example should be used just for development. Does anybody know a repo with a production example of this?

```
import path from 'path'
import express from 'express'
import React from 'react'
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import { ChunkExtractor } from '@loadable/server'

const app = express()

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../public')))

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  /* eslint-disable global-require, import/no-extraneous-dependencies */
  const { default: webpackConfig } = require('../../webpack.config.babel')
  const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware')
  const webpack = require('webpack')
  /* eslint-enable global-require, import/no-extraneous-dependencies */

  const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig)

  app.use(
    webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
      logLevel: 'silent',
      publicPath: '/dist/web',
      writeToDisk(filePath) {
        return /dist\/node\//.test(filePath) || /loadable-stats/.test(filePath)
      },
    }),
  )
}

const nodeStats = path.resolve(
  __dirname,
  '../../public/dist/node/loadable-stats.json',
)

const webStats = path.resolve(
  __dirname,
  '../../public/dist/web/loadable-stats.json',
)

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  const nodeExtractor = new ChunkExtractor({ statsFile: nodeStats })
  const { default: App } = nodeExtractor.requireEntrypoint()

  const webExtractor = new ChunkExtractor({ statsFile: webStats })
  const jsx = webExtractor.collectChunks(<App />)

  const html = renderToString(jsx)

  res.set('content-type', 'text/html')
  res.send(`
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        <head>
        ${webExtractor.getLinkTags()}
        ${webExtractor.getStyleTags()}
        </head>
        <body>
          <div id="main">${html}</div>
          ${webExtractor.getScriptTags()}
        </body>
      </html>
    `)
})

// eslint-disable-next-line no-console
app.listen(9000, () => console.log('Server started http://localhost:9000'))
```